# How can I add column values from a pandas dataframe as a new key value pair in another column having dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for example

```
df = {'dicts':[{'id': 0, 'text': 'Willamette'},
{'id': 1, 'text': 'Valley'}],
 'ner': ["Person", "Location"]}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
```

`
I want end result like

```
{'id': 0, 'text': 'Willamette', 'ner': 'Person'}
{'id': 1, 'text': 'Valley', 'ner': 'Location'}
```

`

I am using following logic but it isn't working for me-

```
for i, rows in df["dicts"].iteritems():
   for cat in df['ner']:
    df["dicts"][i]=df["dicts"][i].update({'ner' : df['ner'][cat]})
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: _I want end result like_ Can you clarify what exactly that output is?

Comment: ner is another column and I want that column  to add a key and cell value as a key value for each row  {'id': 1, 'text': 'Valley', 'ner': 'Location'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
d=pd.DataFrame(df.dicts.tolist(),index=df.index).join(df[['ner']]).to_dict('r')
[{'id': 0, 'text': 'Willamette', 'ner': 'Person'}, {'id': 1, 'text': 'Valley', 'ner': 'Location'}]
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. But I want to add this updated dictionary to the dictionary column from it is taken then how can I do it?